# What data structure is best for large unique records without hitting disk every time?

Tags: java, data-structures

I am trying to develop an application, which contain a long list of sorted unique name, along with exactly one number next to each name. The list is very big in size (10M approx). which data structure is best fit in this scenario. so that I don't hit disk every time. Need expert suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest using any type of min heap or balanced bst with a node containing (name, number) and sorted based on name.

Comment: Why does the list need to be sorted? And how large is “very big”?

Comment: @Bohemian 10 Million +

Comment: How long is the average string? Are they made of only ASCII chars?

Comment: If you add a Cache (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)) you won't have to hit the disk every time

Comment: 10 million isn't actually that large. Assuming 100 bytes per entry, you'd be around 1GB (which on modern hardware can easily fit in memory)

Comment: @Bohemian 15 -20 char long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please say how you will use that structure, I mean for which purposes?

If you use the name for getting number or contra. --> You should use LinkedHashMap for keep order.

Comment: will use name to get contact details

Comment: Thanks Siyar Akhmad

Answer (score 1):

10 million 10-15 char strings doesn’t require much memory.

Use `Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();`, which has constant time, very fast performance.

Comment: Thanks much Bohemian!